# Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: google64

Tags: yum

I just wanna to install vim using yum, however, the yum doesn't work.
And I tried to install other software using yum, the result remains the same.
I remembered typed commands like this: yum clean all, maybe it's the reason that yum doesn't work. How could I repair the yum configuring?

[image: Yum doesn't work]

Comment: This means likely that your repo file is damaged. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Configuring_Yum_and_Yum_Repositories.html

Comment: Is there any way to restore the repo file ?

Comment: Uninstall yum， delete relevant files, and install yum again, then it works again.